# Google Form regex 48 hours at least

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I've created a form in Google with two datetime fields (start and end of event). So i need that the start field only accept date values ​​that are at least 48 hours after than the current date and time. While End field only accept date values ​​equal or superior that Start field value.

Is it possible set this using regex or with Google Script?

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure about doing it in google script but you surely can make a twin form, validate it on your site an by copying the action attribute and names, id's from the original form you can submit it.

Answer (score 0):

### It is a bit tricky

- You can create / edit a form programmatically, [in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)
- However, after you run the corresponding code and update the desired fields - the form will be static
- **If you regularly want to update the allowed start and end time of the event - you can set-up your form editing code on a ([time-driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) ) [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)**
- That is - e.g. every 1 hour your code runs automatically in the background and updates your form
- If you implement within the code something like `var startTime = new Date()` - the code will fetch a fresh timestamp on each trigger execution
- You can set-up the trigger to execute more often, just be careful with [Apps Script quota]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) that specofy a `Triggers total runtime` per day
- An alternative would be to create your own custom HTML form instead of using Google Forms - this would allow you to dynamically adjust the timestamps each time a user loads the form into his browser